# How does this spawner farm work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen a few different mob spawner farm designs around.  Lots of people seem to like this one:

[image: spawner design schematic]

The idea, as far as I understand, is that mobs spawn in the air and fall down through the water suspended by signs.  They then get sucked into the "funnel", pushed over to the water ladder (which they climb by swimming up), then dropped to near-death.

I've seen farms like this in operation in SMP, so I understand the basic principle.  However, I attempted to build one from this schematic, and it doesn't seem to be working.  It seems that the mobs are able to float / swim up on the water blocks below the spawner (above the signs), meaning they never actually fall to the bottom to get sucked up the latter.

As so many people seem to like this design, I'm willing to bet that I made a mistake.  However, looking at the schematic, I see two different places -- the aforementioned water and the water block at the beginning of the "funnel" -- where mobs could get stuck.  How is this farm supposed to work, then?

Comment: I don't see the need for the signs and the layer of water on top of them. The funnel should be a 4x4 hole so multiple mobs can fall through at the same time rather than getting stuck. Maybe that's the issue...hard to tell without seeing your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see in the spawner room is only a side view (and a pretty awkward one at that).

You should cover one edge of the room in source blocks, it will swipe the room and leave you with a 1-block border on the other side. Dig that one down two blocks and place water currents to direct the mobs to the corner (1), where you can connect your elevator.

(1) The picture seems to indicate to gather them in the middle of the edge instead. I would advise against this, as several mobs can block each other at the bottleneck if they come from both sides.

Comment: I agree. I use water source blocks all along one side, let them extend out 8 blocks, and dump the mobs into a trench, which will have another source block pushing them into your funnel.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a similar design many times.  My designs did not use the top layer of signs and water in the spawning area.  Just 2 source blocks in the spawning area, along with a single source block on the bottom to push the mobs to the elevator sufficed.  (Roughly in release 1.7.4 was the last time I used/built one of these).

Answer (score 0):

Here I have some modifications hat might work:

1. Raise the sighns and the waterblocks all by one in the spawning room (except those on the ground).
2. Delete the water and the sign under the spawning room because it is useless.
3. at the beginning of the elevator change it to this patren:

> B ^ B
>   B W B 
>   B S B B B B B B
>   B W S     (mobs come through here)
>   B H F F F F F F
>   B B B B B B B B
>   B = block, S = sign, W = water source, H = half slap, ^ continue the elevator here.

4. Instead of the block you have placed in your room, place a half slap

Answer (score -1):

Possible modification: create the recommended 2x2 column and place the signs so that they are properly spaced. Also, make the design as friendly as possible to the clumsy mobs. Few designs are foolproof (mob-proof).